# UITextView - strange text clipping

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I've placed a `UITextView` into a `UITableViewCell` and sized it how I want. I can see that the size has been set correctly (by setting the text view's background color). . . however the text within the text view has strange clipping.

How can I avoid this?

[image]

Update:

- I ended up placing a `UITextView` onto an empty view in a brand new view controller and *still* noticed the problem.
- Next step was to create a new project and start adding things in one by one.
- Started with a single view controller and view with `UITextView` - ok.
- Added library with convenience methods for view placement - broken.

Comment: I'd try and look into the contentSize property of the textView, it looks like the frame is correct, but contentSize isn't

Comment: @Eugene - thanks. Forgot to mention that I tried setting the content size to something very large. Don't think it's that. . Tho I will add some debug statements of the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by a library that adds some convenience methods for UIView placement. For example it contains methods like:

- view.x = someFloat
- view.width = someWidth

I suspect there was a namespace collision with an internal method used by UITextView, I'm not sure which method caused the problem as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not adjust the height of your table view cell. Implement

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Following the suggestion if Eugene - your content size adjustments might also be responsible. Remember that the `contentSize` will be established only after the text view has been added to its superview. Maybe you should not set the `contentSize` yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I did adjust that actually (see how the label and text view are neatly contained within the cell?). . . I'm working on a forms lib (iBureaucrat) and that method asks the field for its preferred height.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
_textView.frame = CGRectMake(self.x + 20, _label.y + _label.height, self.width - _label.x -14, 66);
```

you are setting the height to 66. I don't see where are you supposed to set it to the cell height.

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
_textView.frame = CGRectMake(self.x + 20, _label.y + _label.height, self.width - _label.x -14, self.height - (_label.y+_label.height));
```

Comment: It should be more dynamic of course, but for now, while I'm trying to isolate the problem, I know that the cell's height is 100, which provides just enough space for a height of 66. . . you can see that the edge of the label (purple color) is just above the cell's bounds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get the part about the background. Now I understand. Have you tried setting the contentInset to 0?

Comment: Thanks. . Yes I tried setting the contentInsets to all different kinds of values, and still no luck. .